# Problem of same indexes with map inside object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use React.js with TypeScript.

I have three arrays:

```js
program_ids = [2, 2, 2]
faculty_ids = [2, 5, 12]
class_ids = [2, 25, 122]
```

Now I want to push each value to the object which I have so in the end I will have array of objects, like this:

```js
obj = [
    {
        program_id: 2,
        faculty_id: 2,
        class_id: 2
    },
    {
        program_id: 2,
        faculty_id: 5,
        class_id: 25
    },
    {
        program_id: 2,
        faculty_id: 12,
        class_id: 122
    }
]
```

I tried this, but it breaks when there are similar program_ids, it thinks that the index is always 0 and pushes first value of each array.

```js
obj = program_ids.map((program_id: any) => ({
    program_id: program_id,
    faculty_id: faculty_ids[program_ids.indexOf(program_id)],
    class_id: class_ids[program_ids.indexOf(program_id)],
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `index` in map. So the code will update like this:

```
obj =
  program_ids.map((program_id, index) => (
    {
      program_id: program_id,
      faculty_id: faculty_ids[index],
      class_id: class_ids[index],
    }
  )
)
```